# dtale show in jupyter book

Tags: html-table, webserver, display, jupyterbook

I use [jupyter book](https://jupyterbook.org/interactive/interactive.html) for creating books from jupyterlab notebooks. dtale tables do not show up in the  jupyter book (they do show up in the jupyter notebook). I read that jupyterbook expects *Interactive outputs will work under the assumption that the outputs they produce have self-contained HTML that works without requiring any external dependencies to load*.
dtale needs a server on port 40000, so does not fit the bill. However, I control the server that servers the jupyter book html pages. Is it possible to configure this html server to support the dtale requests? Any pointers I would appreciate.